# Documentation and syntax for ggplot in python

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

Does anybody know of documentation of ggplot2 in python? To my knowledge the syntax is similar to R syntax, but is there any information or code 
examples out there yet?
Any tutorials....?

Comment: do you meand ggplot? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ggplot/ (i.e. https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/) or there is some other implementation with name ggplot2 in python, unknown to me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We'll be uploading the docs to ggplot.readthedocs.org this week (will update w/ url). Aside from that the best resources are here:

- http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/aggregating-and-plotting-time-series-in-python.html
- http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/ggplot-for-python.html
- http://ggplot.yhathq.com/

The docs just got a major facelift. Still a work in progress but you can check them out here: http://ggplot.yhathq.com/